# Why as? AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason returns nil?

Tags: swift, avfoundation, foundation, avaudiosession

I'm subscribed to the `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`.

Why the following returns `nil`?

```
notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason
```

All the other options work, e.g. return `Optional(2)`:

```
notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey]
notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? UInt
notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? NSNumber
```

I find the first option the most clear/readable.

### Edit 2021-04-15:

In the current Xcode version 12.4 (Swift 5.3.2) it does not return `nil`. The following works now:

```
notification.userInfo?[AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as? AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `userInfo` is an `NSDictionary`, and you can't add Swift enum constants to `NSDictionary`. You **can** add the raw values, though.

That is, it's not legal to declare `userInfo` as something like

```
let userInfo : NSDictionary = [ AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable ]
```

...because you get an error saying `cannot convert value of type '[String : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason]' to specified type 'NSDictionary'`. You **can** declare it like this:

```
let userInfo : NSDictionary = [ AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey : AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.NewDeviceAvailable.rawValue ]
```

This is what you have (or the equivalent of what you have, since the framework is almost certainly using C or Objective-C instead of Swift).

Since `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason` is declared as

```
public enum AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason : Uint {
...
```

The raw values are unsigned integers. You can use `as?` to downcast them to integer types or `NSNumber`, but they're not the same as the actual enum type.

Comment: Oh, I did not know / realize you can not put Swift enum into `NSDictionary`. Now it makes sense. Because you cannot convert raw value (`UInt`) 2 into `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason` using `as?` operator, it does not work. You get a compiler warning when you try to do this directly (`Cast from 'UInt' to unrelated type 'AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason' always fails`). The compiler could issue a similar warning when trying to convert value from `NSDictionary` when it always fails. I'll file a radar. Thanks for clarification!

Comment: FYI, it works now (in current version of Swift). It does not return `nil`. Also the following is now possible: `let userInfo : NSDictionary = [ AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey : AVAudioSession.RouteChangeReason.newDeviceAvailable ]'.